# How to implement file download with Spring MVC in Java?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, download

There is a lot upload examples, but I couldn't find any for download. I'm using Spring 3.0 and I need to generate some text buffer and then let user download it as a file. (There is no static resource.)

So far I've tried to use `@ResponseBody` and writing to response output stream. In both cases browser display content of the 'file' instead of showing Save dialog box. How do I make browser display a dialog box?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the **Content-Disposition** header at your action (and not only the response body):

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=your-file.pdf
```